# Subtract Months with Moment.js Correctly Even After Surpassing February

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there any fix for this or a workaround - even without using Moment.js?

```
<form id="DateFor," class="row-form" method="post" action="">
               <p>
                  <label for="ETL_DATE">Search by date:</label>
                  <span>
                    <script>
                    var curr_month_day = moment();
                    var prev6_month_start = moment().subtract(6, 'months').startOf('month');
                    var prev6_month_end = moment().subtract(6, 'months').endOf('month');
                    var Dur_prev6_month_start = moment.duration({ from: curr_month_day, to: prev6_month_start });
                    var Dur_prev6_month_end = moment.duration({ from: curr_month_day, to: prev6_month_end });
                    document.write('<input data-widget="datepicker" data-format="mmm dd, yyyy" type="text" data-min="' +Math.round(Dur_prev6_month_start.asDays())+ '" data-max="' +Math.round(Dur_prev6_month_end.asDays())+ '" data-select-months="false"  data-select-years="false" value="" size="20" id="ETL_DATE" name="ChangeDatePicker">');
                    </script>
                  </span>
               </p>
            </form>
```

This code returns messed up start and end date for Jan 2017 (currently) - 30 Dec 2016 and 29 Jan 2017. It appears to me that the different number of days in Feb is the root cause.

It should calculate properly the number of days to the first and the last day of January 2017.

EDIT:
I want to confirm that the problem is with '.duration' and '.subtract' of Moment.js.

Comment: You need to explain what you think this code should do, and what it is, exactly, that it isn't.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Thanks - done

Comment: What have you done to compare leap-year selections to non-leap-year selections?

Comment: Oh, wait... Your users shouldn't be able to input an end-date that's before a start-date. This one's good: http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: @admcfajn Yes, I try to make a date picker that gives you only the dates for which there's information on the web-page.

Comment: I want to confirm that the problem is with '.duration' of Moment.js.

Comment: And more precisely - with Moment.js 'subtract'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Folks - I found a workaround though I completely removed the lines of 'Moment.js' and started using just a bit 'Date.js' and normal JavaScript.

This is the fix:

```
<form id="DateFor," class="row-form" method="post" action="">
               <p>
                  <label for="ETL_DATE">Search by date:</label>
                  <span>
                    <script>
                    var curr_month_day = new Date (), y = curr_month_day.getFullYear(), m = curr_month_day.getMonth(), d = curr_month_day.getDate();
                    console.log(m)

                    var prev6_month_begin = new Date(y, m - 6).clearTime().moveToFirstDayOfMonth();
                    var prev6_month_end = new Date(y, m - 6).clearTime().moveToLastDayOfMonth();
                    console.log(prev6_month_begin)
                    console.log(prev6_month_end)
                    var timeDiff = Math.abs(curr_month_day.getTime() - prev6_month_begin.getTime());
                    var Dur_prev6_month_start = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                    console.log(Dur_prev6_month_start);

                    var timeDiff = Math.abs(curr_month_day.getTime() - prev6_month_end.getTime());
                    var Dur_prev6_month_end = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
                    console.log(Dur_prev6_month_end);

                    document.write('<input data-widget="datepicker" data-format="mmm dd, yyyy" type="text" data-min="-' +(Dur_prev6_month_start -1)+ '" data-max="-' +(Dur_prev6_month_end -1)+ '" data-select-months="false"  data-select-years="false" value="" size="20" id="ETL_DATE" name="ChangeDatePicker">');
                    </script>
                  </span>
               </p>
            </form>
```